# Bind method to react state changes

Tags: reactjs

Given the code below, I would like the `transform()` method to run anytime `this.props.code` changes.

```
class Editor extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="pseudo-editor" />
        );
    }

    transform() {
        var editor = ace.edit("pseudo-editor");
        editor.setValue(this.props.code,1);
    }
}
```

I am using react-redux and the state to props binding works as intended.

But Im not quite sure how to approach method binding. I guess its not an alternative to fit my JS code editors API calls inside the render method. Problably a simple solution to this one but could not find an example of which pattern to use here. Thankful for any help.

Comment: Use `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method, it will get called whenever any change happens to props values, check the previous and nextProps values if they are not same call the `transform` method.

Like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(this.props.code != nextProps.code)
        this.transform();
}
```

As per **[DOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)**:

> componentWillReceiveProps() is invoked before a mounted component
>   receives new props. If you need to update the state in response to
>   prop changes (for example, to reset it), you may compare this.props
>   and nextProps and perform state transitions using this.setState() in
>   this method.